# Why is there no {latex} tag?

Tags: support, tagging

I noticed none of the questions on TeX.SE have [latex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/latex) as a tag and I cannot even add it to my question.

Usually I only deal with pure TeX, so having a [latex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/latex) tag would allow me to quickly skip all the questions that won't help me anyway because usually the answer starts with `\usepackage` or `\begin{document}`.

Comment: See for example http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/303

Answer (score 15):

Since the vast majority of questions on the site are about LaTeX, the tag is really not very helpful. Most plain TeX questions will be tagged [plain-tex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plain-tex) but there are at present only 168 such questions, so plain TeX users are few and far between on the site. You can add [plain-tex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plain-tex) (and other tags that interest you) to your favourite tags, but it's true you can't add [latex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/latex) to your list of ignored tags.  I think this is "status by design", given the ubiquity of LaTeX questions.

Comment: Could it be that there are so few questions tagged {plain-tex} because everyone think there's no need to tag because the SE is called "TeX" and not "LaTeX"?

Comment: @AndreKR I don't think so. A lot of tagging is done by experienced users on the site, not just questioners, so plain TeX questions will be quickly tagged as such whether or not the questioner made that assumption.

Comment: If you're looking for `plain-tex` answers to LaTeX questions, we have one user in particular [morbusg](http://tex.stackexchange.com/users/1410/morbusg) who is a Plain TeX user who often provides such answers.

Comment: Oh right, they will be re-tagged of course.

Comment: @AndreKR Also, a lot of question askers don't get the tagging right: knowing if something is [tag:tex-core], [tag:plain-text], _etc._ is something that requires a bit of understanding.

Comment: Thanks for explaining! I was confused when I tried to ask a question and the site told me the `latex` tag is not allowed.